# TCP CONNECTION LAG

Tags: https, tcp

One of my clients is connecting to my server through https:
Apparently, the client gets the reply after 30/40 seconds.
According to tcp dump, I noticed that I am always retrying before the packet is received by the client.

The weird thing is that if I use http instead of https, the problem does not happen. My client's IT say that he is not receiving my packets. I am guessing, a hop or a firewall on the way is blocking my certificate maybe?

PS:

- Client tried postman, c#, and browsers with the same result.
- My server is centos based
- I have 1000 other clients without this problem
- My certificate is not expired and is trusted
- My client had his code running for more than a year and the problem occurred last saturday and is still happening till now. His IT says that nothing was done by them on that day.

Here are the tcp dump I got

```
20:45:38.506687 IP 37.209.251.174.64340 > 104.130.160.218.https: Flags [SEW], seq 1848834203, win 65535, options [mss 1300,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:45:38.506702 IP 104.130.160.218.https > 37.209.251.174.64340: Flags [S.E], seq 813592809, ack 1848834204, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
20:45:39.874861 IP 104.130.160.218.https > 37.209.251.174.64340: Flags [S.E], seq 813592809, ack 1848834204, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
20:45:41.874862 IP 104.130.160.218.https > 37.209.251.174.64340: Flags [S.E], seq 813592809, ack 1848834204, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
20:45:45.874860 IP 104.130.160.218.https > 37.209.251.174.64340: Flags [S.E], seq 813592809, ack 1848834204, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
20:45:53.874863 IP 104.130.160.218.https > 37.209.251.174.64340: Flags [S.E], seq 813592809, ack 1848834204, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 10], length 0
```

Comment: Any proxy server in between to check logs?

Comment: @Khaled kifak (: They say no proxy. On my side no proxy,

Comment: What firewall they have?